# mirror jtextarea to jtextpane

Tags: jtextarea, jtextpane

I was trying to mirror JTextArea to JTextPane.

For JTextArea to JTextArea

```java
JTextArea a = new JTextArea ();
JTextArea b = new JTextArea ();

b.setDocument(a.getDocument());
```

The reason I want to use JTextPane is whenever I type html tags in JTextArea it will be automatically formatted in JTextPane like a webpage.

When I replaced it with JTextPane , it gives me

> *Model must be StyledDocument*

so I've tried adding StyledDocument.

```java
StyledDocument doc = (StyledDocument) a.getDocument();
```

which results to

> javax.swing.text.PlainDocument cannot be cast to
>   javax.swing.text.StyledDocument

How can I achieve this with JTextPane?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong. To achieve what you want, you will need to setup your `JTextPane` to hold an HTMLDocument, and use the methods of this HTMLDocument to insert the content of your `JTextArea` with something like `insertHTML` or using an HTMLEditorKit and its `read` method.

Try something like that:

```java
JTextArea myJta = new JTextArea();
JTextPane myJtp = new JTextPane();
myJtp.setContentType("text/html");
...

public void insertHTML(String html, int location) {
    try {
        HTMLEditorKit kit = (HTMLEditorKit) editor.getEditorKit();
        Document doc = editor.getDocument();
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(html);
        kit.read(reader, doc, location);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
...
insertHTML(myJta.getText(),0);
```